# Ruby/DataMapper find rows where property is empty

Tags: ruby, sqlite, datamapper

I've got the following code:

```
require 'data_mapper'

class Dataset
    include DataMapper::Resource

    property :id,        Serial
    property :name,      String,   :required => true
    property :year,      String,   :required => true

end

DataMapper.setup(:default, "sqlite://#{Dir.pwd}/database.db")
DataMapper.finalize.auto_upgrade!

Dataset.all(:year => nil).each do |dataset|
    puts dataset.inspect
    puts    
end
```

and I want to find all rows where the `year` property is empty. But when i run this script, it gives empty output. When I run it like:

```
Dataset.all(:year => "2005").each do |dataset|
    puts dataset.inspect
    puts    
end
```

I get the correct output:

```
#<Dataset @id=178 @name="Supernatural" @year="2005">
```

Running this query on the sqlite shell gives me 7 rows with empty `year` column:

```
sqlite> SELECT COUNT(`name`) FROM datasets WHERE `year` IS NULL;
COUNT(`name`)
-------------
7
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried searching for an empty string? `:year => ''`, or does your table contain actual NULL values? Frankly it's strange that you're getting NULL at all on a `:required => true` field

Comment: searching for a empty string doesn't work either, I've tried that before. And I have NULL values because I added this field after the application went live, because I added features. And this code is supposed to migrate the database. So I have to find all rows that have not yet been migrated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like the root of the problem then is a poor migration. 
DataMapper thinks there are no rows with NULL year because you told DataMapper there could NOT be any rows with NULL year.

However the database still holds them, so bypassing DatamMapper with raw SQL will yield them.

The solution is to either allow NULLs via DataMapper (`:required => false`), or fix the NULLs in the database (i.e. `UPDATE datasets SET year = '-1' WHERE year IS NULL`)

Comment: I didn't know that DataMapper behave that way on required fields. Thanks for pointing out. I actually just went with a `Dataset.all.each {|ds| if not ds.year.nil? then foobar end}` to solve my problem.